# How to revert Corporate Windows 7 Theme

Tags: vb.net, windows-7, registry, themes

As my Christmas week side-project I thought I'd knock up a quick console app that I can run from the windows Start-up folder.

The application is going to delete some unwanted Global Corporate Desktop Icons (I like to run a clean desktop - is this common?) and Reset the Windows 7 Theme to my lovely Visual Studio 2010 graphics.

I have read the reasons why this shouldn't be done pro grammatically for the user but I feel this case is different as every morning I am manually deleting the icons and resetting the theme (policy is not stopping this - just reapplying it every morning) so I though this little side project could save me time in the long term.

I am deleting the Icons OK but I am struggling to set my theme ala:

> Dim key As RegistryKey = My.Computer.Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Themes", True)
>
> key.SetValue("CurrentTheme", "C:\Users\myprofile\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Themes\VS2010.theme")
>
> key.Close()

This is setting the registry key correctly but not applying it. Any suggestions as to how to make this work or alternatives would be appreciated. Ultimately I may try a simple Wallpaper Set but I would like to use the theme if possible!

Thanks

Comment: Also I'm annoyed I don't yet have the rep to add/create the tag christmas-project - I think this is important information and would like someone higher then me to add it! Cheers :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to P/Invoke to make that change. You'll need to use the [`SetSystemVisualStyle`](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/uxtheme/SetSystemVisualStyle.html) method.

```
<DllImport("UxTheme.DLL", BestFitMapping:=False, CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.Winapi, CharSet:=CharSet.Unicode, EntryPoint:="#65")> _
Shared Function SetSystemVisualStyle(ByVal pszFilename As String, ByVal pszColor As String, ByVal pszSize As String, ByVal dwReserved As Integer) As Integer
End Function

SetSystemVisualStyle("C:\WINDOWS\resources\Themes\Luna\Luna.msstyles", "Metallic", "NormalSize", 0)
```

PInvoke.net is giving me problems right now so you might need to used the [cached page](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3afVcszi0tMO0J%3awww.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/uxtheme/SetSystemVisualStyle.html+pinvoke+uxtheme+dll&cd=2&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us&client=firefox-a).